# Login redirect to tabgroup

Tags: ios, authentication, titanium-mobile

am having troubles on my titanium mobile project. The code below displays a login page which when the login button is clicked, it will re-direct user to the tabGroup.(tab1 and tab2).

```
// this sets the background color of the master
// UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#fff');

// create tab group
var tabGroup;

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'TabViewLogin',
    tabBarHidden:true,
});


var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:10,
    left:10,
    width:300,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Username',
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(username);

var password = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:60,
    left:10,
    width:300,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Password',
    passwordMask:true,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(password);

var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Login',
    top:110,
    width:90,
    height:35,
    borderRadius:1,
    font:{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}
});
win.add(loginBtn);
win.open();

Titanium.App.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
    win.open();
    tabGroup.close();
});

loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if ( tabGroup == undefined ) {
        tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();
        //
        // create base UI tab and root window
        //
        var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
            title:'Tab 1',
            backgroundColor:'#fff'
        });
        var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
            icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
            title:'Tab 1',
            window:win1
        });

        var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#999',
            text:'I am Window 1',
            font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
            textAlign:'center',
            width:'auto'
        });

        win1.add(label1);

        //
        // create controls tab and root window
        //
        var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
            title:'Tab 2',
            backgroundColor:'#eee'
        });
        var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
            icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
            title:'Tab 2',
            window:win2
        });

        var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#999',
            text:'I am Window 2',
            font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
            textAlign:'center',
            width:'auto'
        });

        win2.add(label2);

        var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
            title: "Logout",
            style: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.DONE

        });

        button.addEventListener('click',function(e)
        {
            Ti.App.fireEvent('logout');
        });

        win1.setRightNavButton(button);     
        win2.setRightNavButton(button);     

        //
        //  add tabs
        //
        tabGroup.addTab(tab1);  
        tabGroup.addTab(tab2);  

    } 

    // open tab group
    win.close();
    tabGroup.open();

});
```

BUT the problem now is, i need it to authenticate users first with the code below before re-directly them to the tabGroup.

```
Cloud.Users.create({
    email: 'test@mycompany.com',
    first_name: 'test_firstname',
    last_name: 'test_lastname',
    password: 'test_password',
    password_confirmation: 'test_password'
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
        alert('Success:\n' +
            'id: ' + user.id + '\n' +
            'sessionId: ' + Cloud.sessionId + '\n' +
            'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' +
            'last name: ' + user.last_name);
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

THANKS FOR ANY ASSISTANCE

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ti.App.Properties.setBoolean(key, value)` for storing if user has already loggedin
and `Ti.App.Properties.getBoolean(key, defaultValue)` for checking if user already loggedin.

To switch between tabs from code you can use: [`Titanium.UI.TabGroup.setActiveTab()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-method-setActiveTab) method.

Also try using Alloy which will code responsible for creating view from code which handles events and change state of the app (controller).

Comment: thanks Daniula for your reply. I am quite new to titanium app development though i understand the use of the Ti.APP.Properties but my question is; how do u re-direct users from the login page(after the alert message) to the tabGroup. Any sample code to get me started will be much appreciated. Thanks alot.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that. I added link to documentation for TabGroup.setActiveTab(), which should help you.